# Display current and next Month calendar

Tags: asp.net, calendar

is there a way i can display the current and next month on the calendar just like the screen below
[image]

Answer (score 0):

What is the codebehind that you're finding difficult? 
This should be a piece of cake to do. 
Simply take the month part of DateTime.Now and you have the current month. 
Choose

```
var nextMonth = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1).Month
```

And then construct your visuals around it.

Comment: all i am doing in code is grab what is selected and do something with it but i was the calendar to display two month on the same screen

Comment: What kind of calendar control is it and how do you create them?

Comment: As i noted in the tags this is an asp calendar from visual studio i can select multiple days within the current calendar and use that data which works perfectly fine in code but when i move to the next month and select any date and move back to the current month all my selections are gone. there is a post-back issue within the calendar itself.